# Using sails.js with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sails.js

I followed the sails.js documentation about [using typescript](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-type-script) in sails js app.

Not sure why, I get the following error:

```
error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: `include-all` attempted to `require(project\api\controllers\MyController.js)`, but an error occurred::
Details:project\api\controllers\MyController.js:10
import util = require('util');
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I'm using the same controller as given in the example in the using TypeScript page as mentioned above.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: What version of Sails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and it was because I was using "sails lift" and the documentation said to use "node app.js". Once I used the "node app.js" to start the application it worked as expected.

```
sails lift

info: Starting app...

error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: `include-all` attempted to `require(/research/typeScriptPackage/testing/api/controllers/TsController.ts)`, but an error occurred::
Details:/research/typeScriptPackage/testing/api/controllers/TsController.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import util = require('util');
```

This was the step I missed: 

"5. Start your app with node app.js instead of sails lift."

```
node app.js

info:
info:                .-..-.
info:
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.12.13            |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in `/research/typeScriptPackage/testing`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: -------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Fri Jul 14 2017 08:20:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
```